# java JMenuItem JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, jmenuitem

apologies in advance if this is a stupid question but I've created a window with a menubar and two menuitems....when i click on open i want to use JFileChooser to select a file from my computer but there's an unhandled exception type file not found error on my Scanner input

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("text files", "txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //get the selected file
        java.io.File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        //create scanner for the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //read text from file
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
        //close the file
        input.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file selected");
    }
}
```

I know i should enter a throws Exception but none of my methods will take it....My main method throws an IOException already. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question about the `FileNotFound` exception itself, or about how to modify your code to handle such exceptions in general?

Comment: I want to know where to put the FileNotFound exception because any method I put it in  puts up an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to throw an exception, you will need to surround the code which generates it in a try-catch block, and handle the exception locally like this:

```
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //get the selected file
        java.io.File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            //create scanner for the file
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            //read text from file
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            }
            //close the file
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // handle exception here, e.g. error message to the user
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file selected");
    }
```

Comment: I would be better to close the Scanner in the finally block, there by ensuring the resource was closed regardless of what happended

Comment: `new Scanner(file)` is what throws the `FileNotFoundException`, so in that case there'll be nothing to close.